# How to set a list in two columns?

Tags: lists, columns

I face the following

[image]

Here all  are appears below one by one. Actually I want, the last five are appears in the RHS of the first five. That is , how to align equally in the middle for a good look?

For this, I typed

```
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto \ln x$ 
  \item $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto [x]$
  \item $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$
  \item $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto \tan x$ 
  \item $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$
  \item $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb Z, x \mapsto 5$
  \item $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto e^x$
  \item $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N, x \mapsto 2^x$
  \item $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto \sin x$
  \item $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto x^2$
  \end{enumerate}
```

Any help?

Comment: The command `\Bbb` has been deprecated for more than 20 years. The correct call is `\mathbb{R}`. Also, you should have two formulas per line, like `$f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto\log x$`.

Comment: In my opinion, it's more sensible to have the numbering horizontally first, then vertically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `multicols` and to resume numbering at `5` in the second column. `lipsum` is just to show it merges into surrounding text.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \ln x$ 
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto [x]$
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \tan x$ 
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$
\end{enumerate}
\columnbreak
\begin{enumerate}  \setcounter{enumi}{5}
  \item $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}, x \mapsto 5$
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto e^x$
  \item $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}, x \mapsto 2^x$
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \sin x$
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x^2$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}  
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or without `lipsum` and more importantly with @egreg's hint.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \ln x$ 
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto [x]$
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \tan x$ 
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$
\columnbreak
  \item $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}, x \mapsto 5$
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto e^x$
  \item $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}, x \mapsto 2^x$
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \sin x$
  \item $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x^2$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: sir.... before and after the equtions, texts like **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat
ac, .....** are appears. How to remove this?

Comment: Just a single `enumerate` environment suffices.

Comment: @Chinz Just remove `\lipsum[1]` and `\lipsum[2]`.

Comment: @egreg That's a very good point. I was not aware of that! Mille grazie!

Comment: @marmot: Its working! thank you sir..!

Comment: Since all ten items have the same height, you don't even need the `\columnbreak` statement. :-) On a different subject: In all ten items, `\colon` would be preferable to `:`, as the latter has math status "math-rel".

Comment: @Mico Thanks! I didn't know that either. (IMHO an even bigger improvement would be to end each equation with a semicolon and the others with a period, but different users have different attitudes. I share Barbara Beeton's opinion that equations also require punctuation.)